# unit testing with chai : is there a way to simulate or force a failed transaction?

Tags: transactions, unittesting, chai

Using hardhat and chai, is there a way to simulate/force a transaction failure so the error code will execute?

e.g. with the following, I want it to throw the error because the transaction didn't succeed.

```
function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    uint amount = address(this).balance;
 
    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
    require(success, "Failed to withdraw contract balance");
}
```

Can I do that with chai or another way?

To clarify, the point is to create a test that will execute this line of code

```
require(success, "Failed to withdraw contract balance");
```

with a status of success == false (the transaction failed bit) so the unit tests cover that branch of code, and without altering the code of the contract being tested.

I don't want to do something like put in `!success` or otherwise change the code of the contract being tested. I think that would be bad practice so would like to find another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

minimal code to implement Lauri's suggestion

Target.sol (contract being tested)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract Target {

    address payable owner;

    constructor () {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "only owner");
        _;
    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner{
        uint _balance = address(this).balance;
        (bool success,) = owner.call{value: _balance}("");
        require(success, "Withdraw transaction failed");
    }
}
```

TestHelper.sol
can't receive value as it has neither receive nor fallback functions

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "./Target.sol";

contract TestHelper {

    Target targetContract;

    constructor () {
        targetContract = new Target();
    }

    function targetWithdraw() external {
        targetContract.withdraw();
    }
}
```

target.test.js

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Test target contract withdraw", function () {
    it("reverts as expected on failed transaction", async function () {
        const testHelperFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('TestHelper')
        testHelper = await testHelperFactory.deploy()
        await testHelper.deployed()
        await expect(testHelper.targetWithdraw()).to.be.revertedWith("Withdraw transaction failed")
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two approaches:

1. Test it by using a custom smart contract as the `owner` and `msg.sender` . That contract can then refuse the transfer when you want it to.
2. Change the function to take in the receiver address as a parameter. Then you can easily use a custom contract as a receiver and you can set the contract to refuse the transfer.

I don't think something like `chai` can help you here, since that's basically just syntactic sugar.

Comment: thanks Lauri. @lauri-peltonen
Option 2 is perfect  as it doesn't involve altering the code being tested
I'll post an answer with the minimal code to implement that approach

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a contract that will have balance at your tested contract, it should have a `receive` function that forces revert, this will cause `success` to be false.

```
interface IMyContract {
    function withdraw() external;
}

contract RevertTest {

    function callWithdraw(IMyContract cont) public {
        cont.withdraw();
    }


    receive() external payable {
        revert("no thanks");
    }
}
```

when you call `RevertTest.callWithdraw(mycontract.address)` it should revert with reason "Failed to withdraw contract balance".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending ether to `msg.sender`, send them to a mock contract implementing a `receive()` function that simply reverts. I.e. replace msg.sender with the address of a contract. like shown in the [above answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/129505/72292) except that you don't need a helper contract in order to deploy the base contract and call withdraw as the `msg.sender`.

Answer (score -1):

you can either use truffle-assertions with

```
npm install truffle-assertions
```

in your test code

```
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
await truffleAssert.reverts(contractInstance.withdraw());
```

or you can use a simple try catch with

```
try {
    await contractInstance.withdraw();
} catch(err) {
    Error = err
}
assert.equal(Error.reason, 'not valid!');
```

Comment: unless I'm missing something, this won't create/cause a failed transaction which is what I need to have the code branch to revert

Comment: It works, test it.
truffle-assertions.revert() expects a smart contract function which fails, and in your tests it will be marked as a successful test if the call to contractInstance.withdraw() fails

With the try catch it will work too as in hardhat test a failed contract function returns an exception

https://kalis.me/assert-reverts-solidity-smart-contract-test-truffle/

Comment: yeah, but that's not what the question asks for though. 
It's very easy to test/catch the result of a failed transaction. What I need is a mechanism to make/create a transaction failure. Without that, the code will never go down the failed branch.
I don't need a way to test if something failed, I need a way to *make* it fail and without hacking/changing the contract code. I want to invoke a failed transaction from outside the contract, just like the real world scenario.

Comment: You want your transaction to fail?
That's even easier!
Just call it from an account other than the owner
If what you are looking for is 
    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
to fail, have some invalid call in your fallback function of that smart contract which is what msg.sender.call is calling

Comment: An example would be, create a mock contract just for testing, inherit that contract, and create a fallback function which transfers more eth than the eth it has