# How to cause a .call to revert in hardhat test

Tags: solidity, ether, hardhat, mocha, chai

I am trying to cover all of my lines in my smart contract unit tests with hardhat, and I am not sure how to test the Raffle__TransferFailed() error. Is there some way to force this transaction to fail?

The recentWinner variable is a random address from an array of addresses that have funded the contract.

*(The contract has to have a minimum balance due to another custom error not shown.)*

```js
(bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
```

I have tried implementing a solution I saw to a very similar problem from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/129272/unit-testing-with-chai-is-there-a-way-to-simulate-or-force-a-failed-transactio) stack exchange post.

My solidity TestHelper:

```
import "../Raffle.sol";

error TestHelper__SaysNoThanks();

contract TestHelper {

    Raffle raffle;

    constructor(address rafAddr) {
        raffle = Raffle(rafAddr);
    }
    receive() external payable{
        revert TestHelper__SaysNoThanks();
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        raffle.enterRaffle{value: msg.value}();
    }
}
```

My javascript test:

```js
describe.only("TestHelper for 100% coverage", function () {
              it("should revert if funds aren't transfered to winner", async function () {
                  const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
                      "TestHelper",
                      deployer
                  )
                  //console.log(raffle.address)
                  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(raffle.address)
                  await contract.deployed()
                  //console.log(contract.address)
                  const tx = await contract.enterRaffle({
                      value: raffleEntranceFee,
                  })
                  console.log(await raffle.getPlayer(0))
                  network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
                      interval.toNumber() + 1,
                  ])
                  network.provider.send("evm_mine")
                  const txResponse = await raffle.performUpkeep([])
                //   const txReceipt = await txResponse.wait(1)
                //   const requestId = txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId
                //   const players = await raffle.getNumberOfPlayers()
                //   console.log(players.toString())
                  console.log(await raffle.getPlayer(0))
                  console.log(await raffle.getContractBalance())
                  const transactionResponse =
                      await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(
                          1,
                          raffle.address
                      )
                  const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
                  console.log(await raffle.getContractBalance())
                //   console.log(winnerAddr)
                  //console.log(transactionResponse)
                  const winner = await raffle.getRecentWinner()
                  console.log(winner)
              })
          })
```

The problem I encounter now is that the `transactionResponse` doesn't fail, but it also doesn't send the funds, revert, or emit the WinnerPicked() event.
I have used console.logs to see that the Raffle contract balance doesn't change after `fulfillRandomWords()` is called. Also the recentWinenr is the default 0x00000000 address, despite the TestHelper address being entered into the raffle. The address is even returned when I call `raffle.getPlayer(0)`.

Here is what my terminal returns:
[image]

Here is the fulfillRandomWords() function from the VRFCoordinatorMock:

```
function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 _requestId, address _consumer) external {
    uint256 startGas = gasleft();
    if (s_requests[_requestId].subId == 0) {
      revert("nonexistent request");
    }
    Request memory req = s_requests[_requestId];

    uint256[] memory words = new uint256[](req.numWords);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < req.numWords; i++) {
      words[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(_requestId, i)));
    }
```

Comment: What did you do inside fulfillRandomWords()?

Comment: @always_beta Sorry for super late reply, I've edited the question to include the fulfullRandomWords() function.

Comment: Consider using [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) and you won't have problems like this.

Comment: I think enterRaffle on the raffle contract is reverting but enterRaffle on the helper contract doesn't check for success so doesn't revert

Comment: I assume your contract inherited VRFConsumerBaseV2, thus override fulfillRandomWords function, which will be invoked by vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords function, and you are trying to send the funds to the winner inside your fulfillRandomWords function. Then it seems your winner was the address of 0x0000 and the funds are sent to this address, as like it is burnt, can you check the logic again to see if your winner is picked correctly?

Comment: @always_beta The winner is chosen from an array of addresses that have entered the raffle so the 0x000 address being picked as the winner shouldn't be possible

Comment: @RohanNero  Try import "hardhat/console.sol"; in your contract and print those variables to see if the have correct values

Comment: @always_beta I added a console.log(s_recentWinner) inside the fulfillRandomWords() after the winner is chosen and the winner address is the testHelper address, so I think the function is reverting correctly I just need to figure out how to listen for that custom error()

Comment: to revert a function just use `require(false,"whatever")`

Answer (score 0):

To get the `.call` to fail you need to try and send the funds to a contract that doesn't have a `receive()` or `fallback()` function.

Here is what my TestHelper.sol contract looks like:

```
contract TestHelper {
    FundMe fundMeContract;
    bool public callResponse;

    constructor(address priceFeedAddress) {
        fundMeContract = new FundMe(priceFeedAddress);
    }

    // Use this function to fund the TestHelper contract since
    // it does not have a receive() or fallback() function
    function initialFunding() public payable {}

    // Send funds to allow withdrawal attempt
    function fundMeFund(uint256 sendValue) public payable {
        (bool callSuccess, ) = address(fundMeContract).call{ value: sendValue }(
            ""
        );
        callResponse = callSuccess;
    }

    // Attempt withdrawal that will fail as this contract TestHelper
    // does not have a receive() or fallback() function
    function fundMeWithdraw() public payable {
        fundMeContract.withdraw();
    }
}
```

Comment: The outcome is the same regardless if I have that receive() in my testHelper.sol or not, I think the tx is reverting, I just need to figure out how to listen for it inside the unit test.